# Information from 3 tables with only 2 having matching columns

Tags: sql, join

What is the Sales Tax Rate, StateProvinceCode and CountryRegionCode for [Name]

The information can be found in AdventureWorks2012 - `[Sales.SalesTaxRate]`, `[Sales.SalesTerritory]` and `[Person.StateProvinceCode]`. In this case an OUTER LEFT JOIN could have solved the riddle; the only catch is that only two tables have matching columns. And `CROSS JOIN`ing would only create a more complex table.

So, what method would work, if any, to extract this information? (for example, Utah State)

Comment: Could you show us the whole structure of the 3 tables and what the matching columns are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you wanted.

```
select * from
Sales.SalesTaxRate st
inner join Person.StateProvince sp on st.StateProvinceID = sp.StateProvinceID
inner join Sales.SalesTerritory sat on sp.TerritoryID = sat.TerritoryID
where st.Name like 'Utah%'
```

Comment: __ __| |                    |       \ \   /            
    |   __ \    _` |  __ \   |  /     \   /  _ \  |   | 
    |   | | |  (   |  |   |    <         |  (   | |   | 
   _|  _| |_| \__,_| _|  _| _|\_\       _| \___/ \__,_| 
                                                           THANK YOU Mr. Mukund. This is exactly what I aimed to do. Your help is highly appreciated.